# Вывести на экран все числа с помощью цикла while в интервале от 0 до 6 включительно, кроме чисел 3 и 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num = -1

while num < 6:
    num += 1
    if num == 3 or num == 5:
        continue
    print(num)
```

Выполнил исключения чисел 3 и 5 с помощью оператора continue. Вопрос в следующем: можно ли исключить числа 3 и 5 без оператора continue ?

Comment: Можно инвертировать условие и положить `print` в `if`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а можно поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не знаю python =)

Comment: @Сергей только не `or`, а `and`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я разместил ваш ответ  - сделайте лучше копипаст и я свой удалю (вообще такой уровень кода вы могли сразу в ответ помещать, даже не зная Python:-)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, работает, действительно надо было вместо or, использовать оператор and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант Алексея (@Alexey Ten):

```
num = -1

while num < 6:
    num += 1
    if num != 3 and num != 5:
        print(num)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Владимир традиционно всем рекомендую почитать про [законы де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Вкратце - при внесении отрицания в скобки `and` меняется на `or` и наоборот: `not (num == 3 or num == 5)` => `num != 3 and num != 5`

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно вызывать вывод числа при том случае, если `num` не входит в список `[3, 5]` — включение производится при помощи оператора `in`:

```py
num = 0

while num <= 6:
    if num not in [3, 5]:
        print(num)
    num += 1
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ, всё работает.

Comment: @Владимир в таком случае предлагаю отметить один из ответов как верный, нажав на галочку слева от текста (ещё можно их плюсануть, если что :D)